# MySQL, php table question (delete on an update)

Tags: php, mysql

I have the two following tables

```
table A

| id | name |
| 1  | bob |
| 2  | jill |
| 3  | jojo |
```

Table A is displayed by using checkboxes.

On the first go, the user checks all three checkboxes so you get the result in table B.

```
table B

| table_a_id | table_c_id |
| 1          |   2        |
| 2          |   2        |
| 3          |   2        |
```

But the next time the user goes to edit, they UNCHECK '2' so that it's only:

```
1
3
```

How do I write my query (using either mySQL or php) so that TABLE B is updated to:

```
| table_a_id | table_c_id |
| 1          |   2        |
| 3          |   2        |
```

Comment: " 'table_cd_id=2' " didn't you mean _c_ ?

Comment: You wanna update table B where table_c_id=2 and table_a_id = 1 and 3 ?

Comment: Yes...I edited my question a bit with the result table I am looking for, hope this clarifies things...

Comment: @redconservatory : your comment is my answer ?

Comment: Ah I see, edited one for time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE A,B 
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON B.table_a_id = A.id
WHERE A.id NOT IN (1,3)
```

Or use InnoDB with a [Foreign key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) `ON DELETE CASCADE`, much simpler :)

Comment: By 'A' and 'B' do you mean the tables A and B?

Comment: I wasn't clear about one thing: A.id = 2 represents a checkbox being unchecked. What if the only values being passed are 1 and 3, is there a way to tell the table to find the 'missing' value and delete that row?

Comment: Yes, with a `A.id NOT IN (1,3)`

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE 
FROM TableB 
WHERE (NOT table_a_id IN (1, 3)) 
    AND (table_c_id = 2)
```